# Getting 2 PFSense routers to communicate with eachother

Tags: networking, router, nat, pfsense, static-routes

I have two routers. R2 can communicate with R1 but R1 can not communicate with R2. I know that we are supposed to resolve this with static routes. I have a screenshot showing all my work. What am I doing wrong?

Everything is in the image

[image: ILLISTRATION]

Comment: What is the effective routing table (under `Status`) of both routers?